# Is there any way embed Google mobile-friendly tool in my website?

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

I have a PHP site and want my visitors check mobile-friendly tool via Google. 
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/

Is it possible embed this tool on my site? Or any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the very same question and eventually came up with the following solution

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/" width="600" height="500"> <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p> </iframe>
```

This works fairly well but ironically the iframe is not responsive enough to all devices!!  Looking for code to make the iframe auto respond and would appreciate any ideas..